# StyleCop SA1630

Tags: c#, stylecop

What difference between this methods, why SortDropDown is correct but Page_load and GetCases are not ?

I cant understand.

And how to fix this?

[image]

**Edit** cant see well on picture

Code:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Sort items in drop down list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dropDown">Drop down list</param>
        internal static void SortDropDown(ref DropDownList dropDown)
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// PageLoad event handler 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event Args</param>
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get all cases by authority and ShopNo
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="authority">Authority</param>
        /// <param name="shopNo">Shop No</param>
        /// <returns>Cases list</returns>
        private static IEnumerable<CaseSummary> GetCases(string authority, string shopNo)
        {

        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots of code. This is very hard to read and impossible to edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of your parameters have a single word as documentation, which is obviously not enough (at least 10 characters + at least a whitespace are required).

- `Sender`
- `Authority`

Write a useful description about what is the purpose of these parameters.

Also, for event handlers, you really should adopt the documentation text that Microsoft uses:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the XXXXX event of YYYY.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But  is it necessary to put "." in end of description ? or its like "good style" of documentation?

Comment: @andronz AFAIK, no. But at least 10 characters are required, so maybe there isn't enough without your "."...

Comment: I suggest that you use proper spelling, capitalization and punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the documentation uses one word to describe one of the parameters for the `Page_Load()` event and `GetCases()` method, whereas the `SortDropDown()` method documentation uses more than one word to describe its parameter. Be more descriptive and you will avoid this rule violation.